# How to use nltk.Text findall() API to determine success and failure in client logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I can use the [findall](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.Text.findall)() API without and issue. Below is the simple case

```
import nltk

raw = "Management Discussion and Analysis"
raw = raw.lower()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
text.findall(r"<.*> <.*> <.*> <analysis>")
```

**Output**

management discussion and analysis

---

Now if I change the `raw` variable so that findall does not find anything.

```
import nltk

raw = "Management Discussion and Analysisss"
raw = raw.lower()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
text.findall(r"<.*> <.*> <.*> <analysis>")
```

**Output**

---

So the question is **how to distinguish at the caller side between success and failure?.**

I also checked and debugged the library code and the implementation is to just print the content and return nothing. I found it little strange but do not know why API does not return anything.

```
hits = self._token_searcher.findall(regexp)
hits = [" ".join(h) for h in hits]
print(tokenwrap(hits, "; "))
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

With further working on this, I was able to think/implement a logic which worked for my requirement. I posted the answer so that somebody else can refer it in future.

```
def nltk_text_findall_object(nltkText, regexp):
    outList      = []
    finalOutList = []

    # now assign stdout handle with some text file so that
    # nltk findall() API output/print could be redirected.
    tempFileName = "tempFile.txt"
    orig_out = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = open(tempFileName, "w")

    nltkText.findall(regexp)
    # now restore the stdout handle with original value.
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdout = orig_out

    # Now check for the content in the file and return the list.
    file = open(tempFileName,"r")
    raw = file.read()
    file.close()
    # nltk findall() API returns the list of strings separated
    # by ; as per their current implementation.
    outList = raw.split(";")
    outList = [str(item).strip() for item in outList]
    for item in outList:
        if(len(item) > 1):
            finalOutList.append(item)
    
    
    # now we are done with the file, let's us delete it.
    os.remove(tempFileName)
    return finalOutList
```

**Client Logic To Use Above Method**

```
raw = "Management Discussion and Analysis"
raw = raw.lower()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
regex  = r"<.*> <.*> <.*> <analysis>"
outList = nltk_text_findall_object(text, regex)
if(len(outList) == 0):
    print("Did Not Found")
else:
    print("Found")
```

Kindly somebody let me know in case there is better way to achieve/implement use case posted in my question.